# Microsoft Graph email with a particular changeKey

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to know if there is a possibility of getting an email with a particular changeKey.  I tried to do apply filtering on the changeKey but it did not work.

[image: ChangeKey Does not support filtering]

Answer (score 1):

As clearly mentioned in the response ChangeKey does not support filtering with the current version of Microsoft Graph-Api. You need to find another approach here.

Comment: I already know it does not work in the way I tried! Your answer just states the obvious.  I would like to know if it can be done at all (I think most probably not) or if it can be done I would like to know how.